# OK to ask questions related to tool setup for Salesforce dev?

Tags: discussion

I need some help getting IntelliJ and Azure DevOps repository connected for Salesforce dev. I cannot figure out how to connect the Azure DevOps to IntelliJ to add code to the repo.

Is it OK to ask this question on Salesforce Stack Exchange? Or, is this question more appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion that question would be on topic here.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Here's my new question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320763/how-to-setup-azure-devops-with-intellij-and-illuminated-cloud-for-salesforce-dev